# Inverse of a metric tensor on a Hermitian manifold

Tags: metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, notation, complex-numbers

Let $(M, g)$ be a [Hermitian manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_manifold). We have a metric tensor $g^{i \bar j} dz_i \otimes d\bar{z_j}$, where $(g_{i \bar j})$ is a hermitian positive definite matrix. Now we naturally get the inverse of the metric $(g^{i \bar j})$. I have been told being inverse to each other would imply: $g^{p \bar k} g_{q \bar k} = \delta_{pq}$ which makes no sense to me. I think matrix multiplication should give us $g^{p \bar k} g_{k \bar q} = \delta_{pq}$.

Comment: Thanks for editing! Do you maybe know the reason for the indexing? @Qmechanic

Answer (score 0):

Metric tensors are usually assumed to be symmetrical, i.e. $g_{\mu\nu} = g_{\nu\mu}$, so
\begin{equation}
g_{\mu\nu}g^{\nu\epsilon} = g_{\nu\mu}g^{\nu\epsilon} = \delta_\mu^{\ \ \epsilon}
\end{equation}

The symmetry is due to the fact that the metric is used to compute the line elements $ds^2$ and the follwing holds 
\begin{equation}
ds^2 = g_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu = g_{\nu\mu} dx^\nu dx^\mu
\end{equation}
(I used the Einstein convention on repeated indices).

Comment: Note the component of a hermitian metric is only conjugate symmetrc

Comment: @Chris My bad, I will try to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

The inverse property implies $$\sum_k(g^{-1})^{pk} g_{kq}+\sum_{\bar{k}}(g^{-1})^{p\bar{k}} g_{\bar{k}q} ~=~ \delta^p_q.$$ 
It is standard convention to not write the power "$-1$" explicitly for the inverse metric. Next use symmetry $g_{\bar{k}q}=g_{q\bar{k}}$ and that for a Hermitian metric $g_{kq}=0$ to obtain the sought-for relation.

Comment: But the matrix we are considering here is $(g_{i \bar j})$ whose ij-entry is $g_{i \bar j}$. The same for the inverse of it. So the multiplication of them should be $g_{i \bar j} g^{j \bar k}$.